# UIActivityViewController - Facebook, works perfectly on simulator, but not on a device

Tags: swift, facebook, simulator, uiactivityviewcontroller

When I run through the Xcode simulator, I can post both a picture and a url. One a device, however, I get an entirely different dialog.

I've used another example on here to illustrate the code

```
    let myWebsite = NSURL(string:"http://www.google.com/")
    let img: UIImage = imageView.image!

    guard let url = myWebsite else {
        print("nothing found")
        return
    }

    let shareItems:Array = [img, url]
    let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo]
    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

On the simulator, the dialog comes up perfectly, and it posts both the picture and url to Facebook.

When I run the exact same example on my phone, a totally different dialog comes up, where I'm asked to add a line ("say something about this") and then it posts this headline, along with the google url

Interestingly enough, on the simulator, the url is posted as a url in Facebook, on the device, it's posted as a hyperlink.

Ultimately, I would like the the image and the hyperlink to appear on Facebook. However, if I was able to get the image and the url to post, I would be thrilled.

Has anyone had similar experiences?

Comment: may be in the simulator you are getting the default facebook popup and in the device you get popup from the facebook app, or both can have different os version

Comment: For sure. The popup is different between the simulator and the device, no question. However, I can't find any indication that the API will not work. And it seems crazy that they would diminish the capability.

Comment: I think in your iphone you have FaceBook app installed,If it so you can't share text in FB and there are some other privacy.To know more check it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control)